# how to use core-scroll-threshold in core-scroll-header-panel corectly?

Tags: polymer, core-scroll-header-panel

```
   #scrollpanel{
      border: 1px solid blue;
      height:100%;
    }
    .contentcontainer {
      margin:60px 0;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }


<core-scroll-threshold id="threshold" scrollTarget="{{$.scrollpanel}}" lowerThreshold="10" on-lower-trigger="{{loadMore}}" fit></core-scroll-threshold>
    <core-scroll-header-panel id="scrollpanel" condenses="true" keepCondensedHeader scrollAwayTopbar="false">
      <!-- toolbar -->
      <core-toolbar class="tall">
        <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
        <div flex></div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
        <div id="title" class="bottom indent title">{{category}}</div>
      </core-toolbar>
      <!-- end -->
      <!-- my literation items -->
     <div layout vertical class="contentcontainer">
       <template repeat="{{articlecatalog in articlecatalogs}}">
          <div layout horizontal  class="rowcontent">
            <div flex></div>
            <div flex two>
              <core-selector>
                <div style="border: 1px solid #bebebe; padding: 16px; margin: 16px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #fff; color: #555;">
                  <div style="display: inline-block; height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 50%; background: #ddd; line-height: 64px; font-size: 30px; color: #666; text-align: center;">Q</div>
                  <div style="font-size: 22px; padding: 8px 0 16px; color: #888;"></div>
                  <div style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 8px;">{{articlecatalog.title}}</div>
                  <div style="font-size: 12px;">{{articlecatalog.description}}</div>
                </div>
              </core-selector>
            </div>
            <div flex></div>
          </div>
        </template>
        <div hidden?="{{!$.threshold.lowerTriggered}}">Please wait...</div>
      </div>
      <!-- end -->
    </core-scroll-header-panel>
```

Above are my main codes to implement scroll threshold,what problem i met is no matter what `lowerThreshold` is set,when i scroll the page,even just a little,it triggered the `lower-trigger` event.how to correctly use the core-scroll-threshlod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the scroller property of the element not the element isn't self.

```
scrollTarget="{{$.scrollpanel.scroller}}"
```

example 
http://plnkr.co/edit/01QR1KKbs89t31pSnwxW?p=preview

Comment: I tried your method ,didn't work,there is at least two scroller on right side in core-scroll-header-panel~

Comment: Make a variable this.scroller = this.$.scrollpanel.scroller then bind that variable to the scroll target scrollTarget="{{scroller}}". I have never seen that syntax in binding. I will make a working example when I get to a real keyboard. Typing code on touchscreen isn't working for me.

Comment: that is awesome,thanks,but i'm not seeing any id named $.scrollpanel.scroller ,what is scroller reference for?

Comment: the scroller property of core-scroll-header-panel and core-header-panels as well just returns the scrollable element. which in this case is a div with a id of "mainContainer"

Comment: thanks,i seem to understand it ,in my case,my main content is in the core-scroll-header-panel,and in that panel has a scroller property which is div that wrap the content,if i want the content be scrollable,i should specify the panel to the threshold.